# Show that the difference quotient of holomorphic $f$ is holomorphic in $z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

> Suppose $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic. Let $z_0 \in \Omega$ and define
> $$F(z) = \begin{cases}
> \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} & z \in \Omega \setminus \{z_0\}\\
> f'(z_0) & z = z_0
> \end{cases}$$
> Show that $F$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ with
> $$
> F^{(k)}(z_0) = \frac{f^{(k + 1)} (z_0)}{k+1}
> $$
> for all $k = 0, 1, 2, ...$.

I am a bit stuck on this question. Its easy to show that it is holomorphic for $z \neq z_0$ since it is a sum and division of holomorphic functions for which $z-z_0 \neq 0$. But to prove that it is holomorphic in $z = z_0$, I tried with the definition of the limit,
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{F(z_0+h)-F(z_0)}{h}$$ but I got stuck, can't simplify it any more and don't know how to get $F^{(k)}(z_0) = \frac{f^{(k)} (z_0)}{k+1}$.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Use the Taylor series of $f$ at $z_0$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $F^{(k)}(z_0) = \frac{f^{(k+1)} (z_0)}{k+1}$?

Comment: With Taylor Series I know that $f = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}(z-z_0)^n. But what am I supposed to do then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $z \in B_r(z_0) \subset \Omega $ is
$$
 f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!} (z-z_0)^k \, .
$$
It follows that for $z \in B_r(z_0) \setminus \{ z_0 \}$
$$ \tag{$*$}
F(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!} (z-z_0)^{k-1} 
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k+1)}(z_0)}{(k+1)!} (z-z_0)^k 
$$
and that equation holds for $z=z_0$ as well.

The right-hand side of $(*)$ is a convergent power series in $ B_r(z_0)$ and therefore holomorphic in that disk. It follows that $F$ is holomorphic in $B_r(z_0)$.

The uniqueness of Taylor series then shows that
$$
\frac{F^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!} = \frac{f^{(k+1)}(z_0)}{(k+1)!}
$$
for all integers $k \ge 0$.

Comment: Oh wow, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!